# Possible to compile, then run java program in Atom?

Tags: java, bash, plugins, atom-editor, shortcut

I have installed the "script" package that lets you run code within the Atom application. Problem is when I try to run a java program I get this message:

[image: error message]

Message is the same that I get when I try to run a .java program in bash (without compiling it), which leads me to think that the "script"-addon doesn't automatically compile before running. Is there a way to quickly compile and run a .java file in Atom? Saves a lot of time.